# Returning Null Pointer Exception BUT expected MovieListException?

Tags: java, junit, exception, nullpointerexception, try-catch

So I am running a JUnit Test, which gets the rating of the movie(***Hashmap***:  `HashMap<String, Rating> movieList)`)  ***BUT if there is no rating against a movie throw MovieListException.***

**JUNIT expected vs actual**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnFE1.jpg

**Learning about Throwing exceptions so I don't know what I am doing wrong?**

- In the Rating class I check whether object value is null, then throw `MovieListException`
- In `MovieList` class this line is getting error of null: `Integer value = movieList.get(string).getRating();` EVEN though I am catching and returning the e object ***(Which I assume it need to RETURN? BASED on JUNIT TEST?)***

> ISSUE: I am getting a null pointer instead of my `MovieListException`

**The test class**

```
    /* Test 5: Can't get a rating for an unrated movie
     */
    @Test(expected = MovieListException.class)
    public void nonexistentRating() throws MovieListException {
        String result = movies.getRating("The Ghost in the Invisible Bikini");

    }
```

**MovieList class**

```
public class MovieList {
private HashMap<String, Rating> movieList = new HashMap<String, Rating>();

public void addMovie(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    movieList.put(string, new Rating(RatingType.NONE, null));
}



public String getRating(String string) throws MovieListException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String ratingString = "";

    try {
        Integer value = movieList.get(string).getRating();

        if(value != null && value > 0) {
            for(int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
                ratingString += "*";
            } 
            return ratingString;
        }                   
    } catch(MovieListException e) {
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        return e.getMessage();
    }


    return "No rating";
}

public void setRating(String string, Rating rating) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    movieList.replace(string,  rating);
}

package movieListQuestion;
```

**Rating class**

```
public class Rating {


private Integer ratingValue;
private RatingType typeValue;

public Rating(RatingType type, Integer rating) {
    this.ratingValue = rating;
    this.typeValue = type;
}   

public Integer getRating() throws MovieListException {
    if(this.ratingValue == null) {
        throw new MovieListException("No rating");
    }
    return this.ratingValue;
}
```

}

**Exception class**

```
    package movieListQuestion;

/* A trivial exception class for the Movie List program.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MovieListException extends Exception {

    public MovieListException() {
        super();
    }

    public MovieListException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

**UPDATED getRating method from MovieList class**

```
public String getRating(String string) throws MovieListException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String ratingString = "";

            Integer value = movieList.get(string).getRating();

            if (!movieList.containsKey(string)) {
               throw new MovieListException("Movie not found");
            }

            if(value != null && value > 0) {
                for(int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
                    ratingString += "*";
                } 
                return ratingString;
            }                   


        return "No rating";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `NullPointerException` at `movieList.get(string).getRating()` is evident that the movie you search for is not in the `movieList`

You might decide to throw the same `MovieListException` when a movie is not found. You can do it as

```
if (!movieList.containsKey(string)) {
   throw new MovieListException("Movie not found");
}
//Rest of the code

//Or using Optional
Rating rating = Optional.ofNullable(movieList.get(string))
        .orElseThrow(() -> new MovieListException("Movie not found"));
Integer value = rating.getRating();
```

Also, you should not be catching a `MovieListException` in `getRating` method

Comment: Where should I be throwing this exception... in the getRating method of the movieList? Can you give me a working example from my code please. New to this

Comment: Just remove the try/catch block in getRating in MovieList class

Comment: Okay, so I made changes to the method, test fails, null pointer. Please check end of question for the updated method highlighted at the end.

Comment: Also I've changed .contains to .containsKey since its a hashmap and I need movie name... ?

Comment: You need to have that block above the line `movieList.get(string).getRating();`

Comment: Did you know you're amazing! It worked. Just to understand I assumed  I'd need a try/catch when some method THROWS an exception down the line... why didn't we do this? Learning.

Comment: When you catch an exception you are not allowing it to propagate back to the caller (unless you rethrow it). You can search for "catching vs throwing exception" to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

The `movieList.get(string)`of `movieList.get(string).getRating();` is `null`. That implies you don't have movie named `string` in `movieList`.

I think you should call below method

```
public void setRating(String string, Rating rating) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    movieList.replace(string,  rating);
}
```

from your junits appropirately.